# VNRectangleObservation - provides four coordinates of the observation bounding box - based on which reference?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, vision

I have developed single view application that detects rectangles using the Vision Framework. The video output and rectangles detected will be displayed in the sublayer of UIView (see image below).  The coordinates provided by  VNRectangleObservation as in CGPoint.  My question is, which is the reference point (0,0)?  Is it the top left of Window or UIView based on the diagram below?

[image]

Documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In UIKit, the origin is in the top left corner, max height and width values of the screen size in points.

In AVFoundation, the origin is in the top left corner, max height and width of 1.

In Vision, origin is in the bottom left corner, max height and width of 1.

You can use [VNImageRectForNormalizedRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/2908993-vnimagerectfornormalizedrect) to normalize your detected rectangle into image coordinates for specific view.